# Connection timeout - AWS Ubuntu instance

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, port

Trying to connect to an AWS Ubuntu server instance via SSH using the IP and .pem provided to me by a client, however, keep encountering the following timeout response:
`connect to host 13.54.24.220 port 22: Operation timed out`

The command I have been using is:

```
chmod 600 Hiko_key.pem 
ssh -v -i Hiko_key.pem ubuntu@13.54.24.220
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 13.54.24.220 [13.54.24.220] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 13.54.24.220 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 13.54.24.220 port 22: Operation timed out
```

- Have set the .pem permissions as per [AWS guides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout) and [online resources](http://devoncmather.com/setting-aws-ec2-instance-lamp-git/).
- Have also pinged and trace routed the server IP as per similar Stack [posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86328/ssh-request-timeout-every-time/86646#86646) on the topic, both of which failing as a result.
- Have tested this on two OSX machines (both of which have firewall turned off), two different home networks, all to no avail.
- A port scan of my own ports does not list port 22 as being open - not sure if this is a contributing factor for external traffic

My client assures me that the server has been setup appropriately for port 22 ipv4 connections.

What other factors on my end may be causing this to fail? I’m straight out of ideas.

Comment: Is your client white listing your IP?  I really don't think it's on your end.

Comment: @stdunbar No, I don’t think so. Why would my IP need to be whitelisted? Wouldn’t the .pem key pair suffice for authentication?

Comment: Authentication yes but a timeout tends to indicate a security group (which works like a firewall) that isn't allowing you in.  This can be down to the IP address, depending on the configuration.  You .pem file and your credentials are not even being used yet - the machine has to allow the connection first.  If you're on a Mac, in a command line can you run `telnet 13.54.24.220 22` (assuming that's the correct IP)?  If it just hangs with a "Trying" message then you can't even talk to the machine, let alone your credentials.

Comment: @stdunbar That’s really insightful, thank you! Your assumption is correct, running `telnet 13.54.24.220 22` (on both machines) simply results in:

`Trying 13.54.24.220...
telnet: connect to address 13.54.24.220: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`

Will contact my clients about getting my IP whitelisted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the client's server instance was set up to be accessed from a limited IP address range which my own IP did not sit within.

Once the instance was changed to allow for IP’s from other locations, the connection succeeded as expected.

Many thanks to @stdunbar for the telnet pointer - this really helped debug what was going on here.